# Cannot access components using reference

Tags: java, swing

I cannot make a reference to the class Colours from the class Square. I have created a reference before, but this seems to be happening when the class extends another class such as Canvas in this case.

Here is my code:

Colours:

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;




public class Colours extends Canvas {

Colours(){
JPanel menupn; 
ButtonGroup group;
JRadioButton square;
JRadioButton rect;
JRadioButton circle;
JFrame frame;
JPanel sqpn;
JPanel crpn;
JPanel rtpn;
Circle Circle;
Rect Rect;
Square Square;

Circle = new Circle();
Rect = new Rect();
Square = new Square(this);
menupn = new JPanel();
group = new ButtonGroup();
square = new JRadioButton("Square");
rect = new JRadioButton("Rectangle");
circle = new JRadioButton("Circle");
frame = new JFrame("Colours");

frame.setSize(1000,500);
frame.setLayout(null);

group.add(square);
group.add(circle);
group.add(rect);
group.setSelected(square.getModel(),true);

square.addActionListener(Square);

circle.addActionListener(Circle);

rect.addActionListener(Rect);

menupn.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
menupn.add(square);
menupn.add(circle);
menupn.add(rect);       
menupn.setBounds(0, 360, 1000, 100);

this.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255));
this.setBounds(0,0,1000,400);

frame.add(menupn);
frame.add(this);



frame.setVisible(true);


}

public void paint(Graphics g){

    g.fillRect(0,0,50,50);
    g.fillOval(100,100,50,50);
    g.fillRect(200,200,100,50);
}



public static void main(String[] args) {

    Colours Colours = new Colours();

}
}
```

Shape:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;



public class Square implements ActionListener {
Colours Colours;
JPanel panel;
JTextField colfld1;
JTextField colfld2;
JTextField colfld3;
JTextField locx;
JTextField locy;


Square(Colours Colours){
    this.Colours = Colours;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    panel = new JPanel();
    colfld1 = new JTextField(3);
    colfld2 = new JTextField(3);
    colfld3 = new JTextField(3);
    locx = new JTextField(4);
    locy = new JTextField(3);
    JLabel positionx = new JLabel("X Axis Position");
    JLabel positiony = new JLabel("Y Axis Position");
    JLabel rgb = new JLabel("RGB Value");
    panel.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0));
    panel.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 200);

}

}
```

I can use all the methods in Colours but do not have access to all it's components. And the classes circle and rectangle are not needed right now. I am a newbie

Comment: I would start by having a read through [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html), not mix heavy and light weight components and understand how [layout manages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) work.  I would also consider taking a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) so you understand how painitng works

Comment: What is the problem.  It looks like you're using `Colors` inside `Square` with the `this.Colours = Colours;` line inside `Square`'s constructor.  Is it giving you an error?

Comment: @Sam I am No it is not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're declaring all Colours' component variables inside its constructor. That means that those variables are  inaccessible outside the constructor. You want to declare them as fields on the class instead.

In other words, move these lines:

```
JPanel menupn;
ButtonGroup group;
JRadioButton square;
JRadioButton rect;
JRadioButton circle;
JFrame frame;
JPanel sqpn;
JPanel crpn;
JPanel rtpn;
Circle Circle;
Rect Rect;
Square Square;
```

Above this line:

```
Colours(){
```

Comment: +1 - Out of curiosity, do you know if it is a problem in java too instantiate a variable of a class as the class name itself e.g. `Colours Colours`? I had never seen that before and was trying to find an answer

Comment: @fdsa Apart from readability, no, I don't think there is an issue

Comment: @fdsa Best to avoid ;)

Comment: @fdsa It's not an error but it's confusing because it goes against common conventions.

Comment: I totally forgot to put the variables outside the constructer. Thanks! It had nothing to do with the extends thing.

Answer (score 3):

All the variables within `Colours` are local to the classes constructor.  This means that they can never be accessed out side of the constructor.

Consider two things...

1. Moving the variables you might want to access later, outside of the constructor
2. Consider using setter and getter methods to gain access to those variables you would like outside classes to have access to.  This prevents other classes from messing with `Colours` in ways you don't want them to

I would alos suggest that you have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html), not mix heavy and light weight (`Canvas` and `JPanel`) components and understand how [layout manages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) work.

I would also consider taking a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) so you understand how painitng works